# How many fence in a given deck? Word Problem with Geometry

Tags: geometry

Here's the problem:

"A circular swimming pool 20 feet in diameter, is enclosed by a wooden deck that is 30 feet wide. What is the area of the deck? How much fence is required to enclose the deck?"

I can answer the first question. The second one, I have no idea because I don't know the measurements of the fence (How am I able to know that? Or is it really needed or not?) Suggestions and clues are welcome here. Thanks.

Comment: I think they're just asking how many feet of fencing you need.  That is they want the outer circumference of the deck. The phrase "How much fence" is strange English, so it's difficult to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

The key word in this question is to “enclose” the deck.

[image]

The length of fence required is the sum of the perimeter of the outer circle (radius = 20 + 30) and that of the inner one (radius = 20).